How to add day of the week to an Outlook calendar invite?
When I receive an calendar invite via outlook, I would like to see what the day of the week is. See the highlighted section of the attached image:

I would like it to say "Thursday" for example, instead of only the date. I have looked extensively for various ways to add this information to all the invites I receive, but to no avail.
Where can I adjust this?
